# Validate input, and if input is invalid ask question again

Tags: java

I'm trying to check if user input is valid (an intgeger). If it's not valid, I want to ask the question again.

```
round = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many rounds do you want to play?"));//set rounds for the game
```

What is the best way to check of the user has actually entered an integer. I want to show an erro message if they type a string, and then ask the question again

Comment: Use a while loop. Keep looping until you have a valid input.

Comment: If `parseInt` can't parse the entered string, it will raise an exception, which you could catch & respond to.

Answer (score 2):

By using do-while asking the user to enter the input and use REGEX `[0-9]+` to see if the input consists of digits or not

```
do{
   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many rounds do you want to play?");
   if(!input.matches("[0-9]+") continue;
   round = Integer.parseInt(input);
   break;
} while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `recursion` to get what you are after.

The basic definition of `recursion` can be found [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java).

> **Recursion** in **java** is a process in which a method calls itself continuously. A method in java that calls itself is called **recursive** method.

```
private int getNumberOfRounds() {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many rounds do you want to play?"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid! Please enter a valid number.");
        return getNumberOfRounds();
    }
}
```

What will happen here is we will keep calling the same method until we get a valid input from the user. This method is not perfect however as you will enter an infinite state until you either break from it.